# Finding index of number from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I am using Python 3, and I have two lists in my code:

```
ListA = [53, 1, 17, 4, 13, 2, 17]
ListB = [4, 3, 1]
```

Now, I want to find the index of any number in ListB that is in ListA.

The output in this case should be `1` because:

- The first value in `ListA` which is also in `ListB` is `1`.
- The index of value `1` in `ListA` is `1`.

Comment: You can use list comprehension as `index = [ListB.index(j) for j in ListA if j in ListB][0]`

Comment: What should happen if there are no common values?

Comment: Depending on your application, `np.in1d()` could be useful: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html

Comment: Should the output be the index of the common value in `ListA` or `ListB`?

Comment: Thanks for fast responses everyone, i will clarify my question. I want to find index in ListA that matches any number from ListB (4, 3 or 1). In example that i posted, number 1 is in ListB and first in ListA (from given numbers in ListB). Expected output is: 2 / or if ListA doesnt have any numbers from ListB, than the output is expexted to be len(ListA). Hope i didn’t confuse you even more now 

Comment: So is it the index 2 because 1 appeared at position 2 in ListA?

Comment: @VitaliKazinski, Indexing in Python begins at 0. So if you need the index of `1` in `ListA` it would be `1` (as the second value).

Comment: Thats right!  i can add +1 at the end of the formula right?

Comment: @VitaliKazinski, Yes, of course you can add 1. You probably don't need our help there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure Python, you can use a generator comprehension with `next` and `enumerate`:

```
A = [53, 1, 17, 4, 13, 2, 17]
B = [4, 3, 1]
B_set = set(B)

first_lst = next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(A) if val in B_set)  # 1
```

Note we hash values in `B` via `set` to optimise lookup cost. Complexity is O(*m* + *n*), where *m* and *n* are number of elements in `A` and `B` respectively. To error handle in case no match is found, you can supply a default argument:

```
first_list = next((idx for idx, val in enumerate(A) if val in B_set), len(A))
```

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use NumPy. No error handling here in case of no match:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([53, 1, 17, 4, 13, 2, 17])
B = np.array([4, 3, 1])

first_np = np.where(np.in1d(A, B))[0][0]  # 1
```

Comment: +1 for numpy. Very convenient if you already work with arrays, so that you don't have to translate them to sets or lists. Also can be adapted for multiple dimensions arrays

Comment: This worked just great, thank you friend very much!  btw i used first solution you suggested

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following generator expression:

```
next(i for i, a in enumerate(ListA) for b in ListB if a == b)
```

Given your sample input, this returns: `1`

Comment: Nice, but the nested `for` loop makes complexity O(*m* * *n*), right? [where `m, n = len(A), len(B)`]. Also index should refer to `A`, not `B`.

Comment: You should enumerate ListA rather than ListB

Comment: @jpp Yes, I wrote this answer in order to give an answer quickly. ;-) I just posted a much more efficient answer separately. You can check it out if you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want better efficiency you can turn `ListB` into a set so that you can determine if an item is in `ListB` with an average time complexity of O(1):

```
setB = set(ListB)
print(next(i for i, a in enumerate(ListA) if a in setB))
```

This outputs: `1`

Answer (score 0):

Set intersection to find the common values. Then find all the indices which are present in ListA and then find the minimum index. If in case there is no match it will print the length of ListA

```
set_inter =set(ListB).intersection(ListA)

if set_inter: # if there is a common value
    idx_A=min([ListA.index(i) for i in set_inter])
    print(idx_A)
else:
    print(len(ListA)) # print the length of ListA
```